# How can I delete from attribute table in a dxf file in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, dxf, cad

I have tried delete one row from an attribute table in a dxf file, but I can't. ArcMap said I need to export that to a geodatabase or something similar.

What exactly should I do?

From step to step, please.

Comment: @Hornbydd - You should really move your comment into an answer.  It might not be what the OP wants to hear, but it is accurate.

Answer (score 3):

In ArcMap a [DXF](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_working_with_CAD_data/00100000002r000000/) file is read only so you need to export it, there is no alternative. Use the [CAD to Geodatabase tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000001z000000).

Comment: I have used that, but I get a geodatabase with only 3 (layers, maybe it's the name of them), and it's consist of only green colored things now. The DXF had Annotation, Point, Polyline, Polygon, MultiPatch, and the conversion consist of a Polyline, Polygon, Annotation. And the cannot be expanded. There isn't anything in them. Why?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit your DXF file, use a Cad program. Many software versions are free, DraftSight, AutoCAD360, doubleCad, NanoCAD, etc.